# How to get data in Angular directive though Ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

Please forgive me if my Title doesn't exactly match with the issue.
I have a custom Angular directive to generate kendo grids dynamically.
I am making an Ajax call to get the configuration from server.
Now issue is, directive first gets loaded and then the ajax call gets completed because of which it is throwing error in my directive.
Please let me know if there is any workaround for this.

**My directive:**

```
gridApp.directive('grid', function () {
return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: true,
    template: '<div kendo-grid="mainGrid" options="gridOptions"></div>',
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, gridService) {
        var gridConfig = gridService.getGridConfig(); //this is undefined. However, when I check in console it gets loaded once the directive is executed.

        //removed for breveity
    }
};
```

});

**My Service:**

```
angularApp.factory('gridService', gridService);

function gridService($http, $q) {
    var getGridConfig = function (gridId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/Base/GetGridConfiguration?GridId=' + gridId)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response.data);
                    });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        getGridConfig: getGridConfig
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

promises are async. you need to use `.then`

```
 gridService.getGridConfig()
    .then(function(data) {
       ////
       // code dependent on server response
       ////
    });
```

RFTD [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Is that a standard way of putting my controls inside .then().

Answer (score 0):

Chnage your service to return deferred object rather than data.

```
return  $http.get('/Base/GetGridConfiguration?GridId=' + gridId)
```

resolve the promise inside the directive.

```
var gridConfig, _self = this;
gridService.getGridConfig().then((response) => {
    _self.gridConfig = response.data;
});
```